# android How to delete the categories

Tags: android

I need some help with this application. I don't know what have I delete or change to show text from quotes without categories. I mean when I press the button, the show apper random without select the categories. I want to delete that categoies.
I am tring for 2 hours but I am beginner, I didn;t find the good way.

```
package com.sv.lovr;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    import com.conceptapps.lovr.R;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
    import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.ScrollView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        ArrayList<Quotes> quotes = new ArrayList<Quotes>();
        Quotes qs = null;
        Context context;

        private AdView adView;

         Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
        private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3126879690773207/7823002769";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            // Create an ad.
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

            context = this;
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ads_lin);
            layout.addView(adView);

            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                    .addTestDevice("5B895A3CC0CA50D56506E300A4C8342B")
                    .addTestDevice("D039292A1F434C999B21503D63D6FD88")


                    .addTestDevice("TEST_EMULATOR").build();

             Start loading the ad in the background.

            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            ImageView share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
            ImageView about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);

            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    loadCategory();
                    Quotes q = randomString();
                    qs = q;
                    TextView text_quote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quote);
                    //TextView text_categ = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
                    if (q != null) {
                        text_quote.setText(q.getQuote());
                        text_categ.setText(q.getCateg());
                    }
                }
            });
            share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (qs != null) {
                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, qs.getQuote());
                        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(sendIntent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Press the lovely button first", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            context);

                    // set title
                    TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                    text.setText("\nLovr is a mobile application designed for all men who want to surprise their life partners. Because we know that the man is not the most creative being on Earth... for God, man is a fighter,a true warrior,he has no time for creative ideas,romantic stuff.But with this app, men from all over the world can surprise their life partners with unique ideas for dating, romantic, dirty or funny messages, and many other things that will make partner loves you more and more.\n\nAttention! For it's best results, confidence, body language, sense of humor skills are highly requiered. More details can be found in the links below.\n David DeAngelo\nhttp://www.doubleyourdating.com/\nThe Attraction Forums \n http://www.theattractionforums.com/ \n Simple Pickup \n https://www.simplepickup.com/ \n Succes Dublu \n http://succesdublu.ro/ \n Double Your Dating | Learn About My eBook \n www.doubleyourdating.com \n\nApp created by:\n Stroe Andrei Catalin\nE-mail:catalin2402@yahoo.com\n\n Visan Tiberiu\n E-mail:tiberiu.visan@yahoo.ro");

                    ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext());

                    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

                    layout.addView(text);
                    scroll.addView(layout);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setView(scroll);

                    // set dialog message
                    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null).setTitle("About");

                    // create alert dialog
                    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog
                            .setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                                    Button b = alertDialog
                                            .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                                    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });
                    // show it
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (adView != null) {
                adView.resume();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            if (adView != null) {
                adView.pause();
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            // Destroy the AdView.
            if (adView != null) {
                adView.destroy();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        /*public void loadCategory() {
            CheckBox check0 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
            CheckBox check1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
            CheckBox check2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
            CheckBox check3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.radio3);
            String[] categ;
            quotes.clear();
            if (check0.isChecked()) {
                categ = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categ1);
                for (int i = 0; i < categ.length; i++) {
                    Quotes c = new Quotes(categ[i], getResources().getString(
                            R.string.categ_1));
                    quotes.add(c);
                }
            }
            if (check1.isChecked()) {
                categ = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categ2);
                for (int i = 0; i < categ.length; i++) {
                    Quotes c = new Quotes(categ[i], getResources().getString(
                            R.string.categ_2));
                    quotes.add(c);
                }
            }
            if (check2.isChecked()) {
                categ = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categ3);
                for (int i = 0; i < categ.length; i++) {
                    Quotes c = new Quotes(categ[i], getResources().getString(
                            R.string.categ_3));
                    quotes.add(c);
                }
            }
            if (check3.isChecked()) {
                categ = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categ4);
                for (int i = 0; i < categ.length; i++) {
                    Quotes c = new Quotes(categ[i], getResources().getString(
                            R.string.categ_4));
                    quotes.add(c);
                }
            }
        }

        public Quotes randomString() {
            int size = quotes.size();
            Quotes selected_quote = null;
            Random r = new Random();
            if (size != 0) {
                int number = r.nextInt(size);
                selected_quote = quotes.get(number);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select a category",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return selected_quote;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but, from what I've understood. To make the code at least to compile you need to:

1) Comment this line:
`Start loading the ad in the background.`

So it should look like this:
`//Start loading the ad in the background.`

2) Comment or erase all the `loadCategory();` you have in your code

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

I commented the line loadCateogy(); but to no luck. If the category is not checked the text doesn't appear when I press the button.